# Horizontal alignment of Spring checkboxes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, checkbox

I have this code

```
<form:checkboxes path="domainContainerArray"  items="${checkBoxesMap}"/>
```

It is Displaying checkBoxes in vertical direction like this
[image]

I searched alot and even tried to apply css but I failed.How can I align them Horizontally? Any suggestions?
 **EDIT:** The mark up generated by code

```
<fieldset style="float: right">
<span>
<input id="d1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="dTypeContainerArray">
<label for="d1">Item 1</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="d2" type="checkbox" value="2" name="dTypeContainerArray">
<label for="d2">Item 2</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="d3" type="checkbox" value="3" name="dTypeContainerArray">
<label for="d3">item 3</label>
</span>
   ........
<span>
<input id="d7" type="checkbox" value="7" name="dTypeContainerArray">
<label for="d7">Media</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="d8" type="checkbox" value="8" name="dTypeContainerArray">
<label for="d8">Misc</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="d9" type="checkbox" value="9" name="dTypeContainerArray">
<label for="d9">Open Source Int</label>
</span>
<input type="hidden" value="on" name="_dTypeContainerArray">
<input class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit" onclick="changeFormAction('2/76/finalize')" style="border-radius: 0" value="Check Button" role="button">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: could you post the markup spring generates for these?  If I see the markup I can provide you with the css.

Comment: See the update question .. Actually I need the Css

Comment: I'm not seeing any updates.

Comment: Interesting... You must have some other css affecting the checkboxes, here is what the raw html produces: http://jsfiddle.net/jzdL3/  Are you familiar with firebug?

Comment: Yes I copied this from Firebug

Comment: inspect the styles, it has to be something outside of the generated markup.

Comment: Yes you are right.My problem is not solved but you show me the way towards problem So it would not be bad if I wont accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `checkboxes` tag allows you to specify a `cssClass` attribute.  You can provide a css class that will be applied.  Then just define a style in your css that makes these elements float.

[Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.checkboxes)

The raw html you posted actually aligns the checkboxes horizontally.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzdL3/).  I suspect some other styling on your page is affecting these checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Bootstrap css.  I fixed by overriding the label element style to display: inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-block property for this.
Have a look at this code.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nimmicv/A7bfj/)

```
label {
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
}
```